# omit top border of highcharts chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a columns chart and I need to draw the left, right and bottom lines of the chart (x/y axes) but need to either omit the top line

or ...

draw a white line to cover the top line.  Viewing the raw data in Chrome, I can see the box is drawn using `<rect>`.

Is it possible to use JS to locate that  and get the x,y,width attributes to draw a white line or remove it and replace with 3 black lines

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
        <title>Annual Performance</title>         
        <!-- this code to include Highcharts with jQuery-->         
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>         
        <!-- <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script> -->         
        <!--this code is the required highcharts javascript file -->         
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>         
        <!-- <script src="/js/highcharts.js"></script> -->         
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>         
        <script>
$(function () {
    // Set up the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            margin: 50,
            plotBorderWidth: 3,

        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{y:.2f} %'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {enabled: false},
        yAxis: {
            title: {text: null},
            max: 4,
            allowDecimals: false,
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value + ' %';
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Annual Performance'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'XXX Shares'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [2008, 2.17],
                [2009, 0.15],
                [2010, 0.00],
                [2011, 0.00],
                [2012, 0.01],
                [2013, 0.01],
                [2014, 0.01],
                [2015, 0.00],
                [2016, 0.00],
                [2017, 0.38]
            ],
        }]
    });


});
</script>         
    </head>     
    <body> 
        <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    </body>     
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create additional yAxis and use **lineWidth** and **offset** properties to acheve needed result:

```
xAxis: {
  lineWidth: 3
},
yAxis: [{
  lineWidth: 3,
  offset: -2,
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  max: 4,
  allowDecimals: false,
  labels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return this.value + ' %';
    }
  }
}, {
  opposite: true,
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  offset: -2,
  lineWidth: 3,
}],
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cj497k6s/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.lineWidth